# Integrating socket.io into a Restify API

Tags: node.js, api, socket.io, restify

I'm in the process of integrating socket.io into an existing Restify API. Is it possible to open several socket connections for various GET endpoints of the API? Example of endpoints: /data/:model/:dateRange and /data/:brand/:dateRange. The client would be able to get the latest data from both endpoints every time the data changes on the server.

Is it a better practice to open the socket connection once when the Restify server is initialized and then pass along this connection client messages that contain any endpoint-related parameters (model, dateRange, etc) for data that the server needs to return to the client?

Comment: Your second paragraph is the answer. There is no need to open a socket for every endpoint. Just initiate the socket connection on page load and then set up some listeners at the client side for the types of messages you plan to broadcast from the server.